# display data from database table from different rows but with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this table in my data base

[image]

how can i display the item_sub1 from the second row?

do i need to create for each loop? if so how is the right way to extract the item_sub1 in the second or the third row?

```html
34 2 דרור שליט 053-3380305 drors@10.tv המקור דרור שליט a5 חצובת תאורה לד X 70 no item no item דרור שליט 1 2018-12-15 10:03:44 
35 2 דרור שליט 053-3380305 drors@10.tv המקור דרור שליט g5 X 70 no item no item no item דרור שליט 1 2018-12-15 10:03:45 
36 2 דרור שליט 053-3380305 drors@10.tv המקור דרור שליט a7 חצובת תאורה לד no item no item no item דרור שליט 1 2018-12-15 10:04:19
```

```js
require_once 'app/helpers.php';
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orderout";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
?>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php foreach ($res as $row) : ?>
    <span><?= $row['item_sub1']?></span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
```

i wold like to display only item_sub1 from the second row

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i have tried to create for-each loop but the only result i can display if only for the first row

Comment: Again, please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: It should be a `while ($row = $statement->fetch())` loop.

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: Barmar  can you give me more details with your answer regarding to my question. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mysqli_data_seek()` function to go to a specific row of results.

```
<?php
mysqli_data_seek($res, 2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo "<span>{$row['item_sub1']}</span>";
?>
```

You can also do this in the query itself, using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM orderout LIMIT 1, 1
```

The first number is the offset (starting from `0` for the first row), the second number is the number of rows to return.

Note that unless you use `ORDER BY` in your query, the order of the results is unspecified and will be unpredictable.